# How to use a program designed for older verisions of ubuntu on a newer one

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, programming

I was wondering if there was a way to run a older program designed for a older version of ubuntu on a new one. Specifically Robot OS Fuerte which was designed to work on 12.04 on ubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 0):

There will be no direct way. you can do that with some extra work and luck.The only problem is Dependencies.

If Application needs some kind of dependency either not available or conflicts with existed dependency then its a big problem.

what I suggest ? , I am simply suggesting that do it & if you got any a problem with the installation , start a new question and post.